# How to have some link sand not all the links with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to have the links on this website : https://www.bilansgratuits.fr/secteurs/finance-assurance,k.html

But not all the links, only those : [links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOV3T.png)

Unfortunately my script here give me ALL the links.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
   


url = 'https://www.bilansgratuits.fr/secteurs/finance-assurance,k.html'

links = []

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")


links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]

print(links)
```

Any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the links you want are contained in a div with class name `listeEntreprises` so you can do

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "listeEntreprises"}).find_all('a', href=True)]
```